# How to properly render a button or icon inside Data Grid column?

Tags: material-ui, datagrid

i have a Data Grid table, there's a colomn that holds actions (edit and delete):
(Below is my whole code)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit'
import DeleteForeverIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteForever'
import { Button } from '@mui/material'

const rows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    lastName: 'Snow',
    firstName: 'Jon',
    age: 35,
    edit: EditIcon,
    delete: `${(<Button variant="text">Text</Button>)}`,
  },
]

const Colors = () => {

  const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
    { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First name', width: 130 },
    { field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last name', width: 130 },
    {
      field: 'age',
      headerName: 'Age',
      type: 'number',
      width: 90,
    },
    { field: 'edit', headerName: 'Edit', width: 150 },
    { field: 'delete', headerName: 'Delete', width: 150 },
  ]

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 560, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        sx={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={8}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[8]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Colors
```

Now my problem is, i would like to use a material `icon` inside edit column.
I tried by implementing icon directly like this:

```
const rows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    lastName: 'Snow',
    firstName: 'Jon',
    age: 35,
    edit: EditIcon, //<--
  },
]
```

Or calling a `button` by this way:

```
const rows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    lastName: 'Snow',
    firstName: 'Jon',
    age: 35,
    delete: `${(<Button variant="text">Text</Button>)}`,   //<--
  },
]
```

**Result**: i'm getting a render `[object object]` instead of icon or button.[image]

**How to properly render a button or icon inside Data Grid column?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using [renderCell](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#rendering-cells), with this i can render html inside grid data the way i want (i can put [button](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-a-button-to-every-row-in-material-ui-table-forked-sxqezo?file=/demo.tsx) for exemple):

```
{
   field: 'edit',
   headerName: 'Edit',
   width: 70,
   renderCell: (params) => {
     return <EditIcon />    //<-- Mui icons should be put this way here.
   },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try doing this. MUI exposes an actions column type that you can pass custom icons and implementations to. If you scroll down a bit on this link you can find a lot of column options.

[Actions column](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/)

```js
import { GridActionsCellItem, GridRowParams } from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro";
import EditIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Edit";

    {
      field: "actions",
      type: "actions",
      align: "left",
      headerName: t("actions"),
      getActions: (params: GridRowParams) => [
        <GridActionsCellItem
          key={0}
          icon={<EditIcon titleAccess={t("edit")} color="primary" />}
          label={t("edit")}
          onClick={() => handleEditPressed(params)}
        />,
      ],
    },
```

Comment: Thanks @louis, your answer may work too